# Problem with xaml compliation in AvaloniaUI

Tags: avaloniaui

When i add new View to a project and try to build it this error occurs:

```
`System.Xaml.XamlException: No precompiled XAML found for Test.Views.SchemesView, make sure to specify x:Class and include your XAML file as AvaloniaResource
17:59:18.882 [Error]  Exception caught by FireAndForget
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AvaloniaVS.Services.PreviewerProcess.<OnMessageAsync>d__37.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\AvaloniaVS\Services\PreviewerProcess.cs:line 433
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AvaloniaVS.Services.PreviewerProcess.<OnMessageAsync>d__37.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\AvaloniaVS\Services\PreviewerProcess.cs:line 433<---
`
```

How can it be resolved ?

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

This error means that Avalonia XAML-compiler MSBuild task hasn't processed any XAML for `SchemesView`. It could be caused by several reasons:

- You haven't added your XAML file as `AvaloniaResource` or `EmbeddedResource`
- `x:Class` directive is missing or invalid
- Your project doesn't directly referece `Avalonia` package. As of version `0.9.x` direct reference is required because of compatibility with .NET Core 2.1 SDK, which lacks support for `buildTransitive`. This restriction will be probably lifted in `0.10`.